# Google Apps Script (Calendar) - Compare if 2 events are in the same day

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I don't know JavaScript (I know a little Java) but I want to write a simple script that deletes my school classes events when there is a vacation event but it simply doesn't work... What is the problem?

```
function vacations()                                                 
{                                                    
  var school_calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Timetable")[0].getEvents(new Date("September 1, 2016"),new Date("June 20, 2017"));
  var vacations = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Vacations")[0].getEvents(new Date("September 1, 2016"),new Date("June 20, 2017"));
  for (var i = 0; i < vacations.length; i++)
  {
    var vacation = vacations[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < school_calendar.length; j++) 
    {
      var school_class = school_calendar[j];
      if(vacation.getAllDayStartDate() == school_class.getStartTime())
      {
        school_class.deleteEvent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing a Date `vacation.getAllDayStartDate()`with a Date `school_class.getStartTime()` can work if you compare them like:

```
vacation.getAllDayStartDate().getTime() === school_class.getStartTime().getTime()
```

However, one contains a date with a time set at midnight:

> getAllDayStartDate()
>
> Gets the date on which this all-day calendar event begins. (If this is
>   not an all-day event, then this method will throw an exception.) The
>   returned Date will represent midnight at the beginning of the day on
>   which the event starts in the script's time zone. To use the
>   calendar's time zone instead, call getStartTime().

And the other contains a date and time:

> getStartTime()
>
> Gets the date and time at which this calendar event begins. For
>   non–all-day events, this will be the instant in time at which the
>   event was defined to start. For all-day events, which only store a
>   start date (not a date and time), this will be midnight at the
>   beginning of the day on which the event starts in the calendar's time
>   zone. This allows meaningful comparison of start times for all types
>   of events; however, it will not necessarily preserve the original
>   day-of-year unmodified.
>
> For all-day events, getAllDayStartDate() should almost always be
>   called in preference to this method.

Make sure you compare the right formats, and use the debugger or Logger to see what is going in in the code.